# Implementation for database

Tags: iphone, database

I am new in iPhone, I am trying to make an application in which there is need of database for record.
I do not know how to implement it. Is there any one to help me.

Comment: if you want your question answered, you'll need to give some more details: what do you want to store? Only on the iphone or in a server somewhere, what sort of program do you want to make......

Comment: The answer to this question might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3039910/question-regarding-ideal-database-implementation-for-iphone-app

Answer (score 2):

You can use core data

Check this [Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/934/core-data-tutorial-getting-started)